# How to set up a Jenkins server with cucumber and git?

Tags: git, jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a web app repository on bitbucket.
I also have another a cucumber repository on bitbucket.

I want to do is:

When the remote web app repository is updated, the cucumber test is automatically run. The result is sent to slack.

How should I configure the Jenkins server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try [BitBucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) and [Slack Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin)

Comment: How about cucumber? Is there any easy way to run cucumber in Jenkins?

Comment: you can just install it on your jenkins server

Comment: if it cause the "cucumber: command not found" error when you build the job, try `sudo ln -s {cucumber_home}/bin/cucumber /usr/bin`, that is waht I did before.
hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the master server controls the slave server? Use the following steps:

Install jenkins on master and start it, install jdk on slave.

On master, you should config Credentials, then set up ssh connection on master and slave.

On master's Execute shell conmmand, input something you want to, then input your order on slave.